# dot net nuke uploading files

Tags: file, file-upload, upload, web-config, dotnetnuke

I"m working on a dot net nuke site for a client, they are wanting to upload files of about 60mbs. I have changed the web.config file to allow files up to 65 mbs in size just for wiggle room.

httpRuntime useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" maxRequestLength="66560" requestLengthDiskThreshold="66560" executionTimeout="1080000" />

this is the code in the web.config file. I have personally tried mp3 files ranging from 40 mbs - 60 mbs in size to no luck. The module will only upload files of 28mbs or less. We are using the Live Content module if this  helps.

The connection is getting reset. its not even getting to the 18 minute timeout i have given it, even if it is only set to 3 minute timeout i get same error. Also when uploading the file it will get to 86% then restart when it gets to 86% again is when it gets the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

actually fixed it, the dot net nuke is set to upload files up to 8mbs, the iis is set to only allow files up to 30mbs. adding this code to the web.config file will allow files larger than 200mbs to be uploaded. using the code i provided in my question will modify the dnn's upload but this will modify the iis.

Answer (score 1):

The [wiki on DotNetNuke.com](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/tabid/1409/Page/Working-with-large-files/Default.aspx) gives a complete and thorough explanation of this.

Answer (score 0):

You may also have to increase the value of AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed, see: http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/File_Upload_limits.asp

Comment: thank you this post lead to my answer, which i posted above. Your answer is for iis 6 i'm using iis 7.